Getting error while creating nested map(object) template for monitoring_logging_metric in terraform GCP
getting error while creating nested map(object) template for monitoring_logging_metric in terraform GCP. Trying to create a template resource and passing the values of multiple objects through tfvars file.
main.tf file
resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric" {
  for_each = var.custom_logging_metrics
  name   = each.value.name
  filter = each.value.filter
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = each.value.metric_kind
    value_type  = each.value.value_type
    labels = each.value.labels
}
    label_extractors = each.value.label_extractors
}

.tfvars file
custom_logging_metrics = {
  metric1 = {
    name   = "my-custom-metric-1"
    filter = "resource.type=\"gce_instance\" AND severity>=ERROR AND log_name=\"projects/crafty-acumen-422607-j2/logs/OSConfigAgent\"\n"
metric_kind = "DELTA"
value_type = "INT64"
    labels = {
      message = {
        value_type  = "STRING"
        description = "Error Message"
      }
      timestamp = {
        value_type  = "STRING"
        description = "time of error"
      }
    }
    label_extractors = {
      message   = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.message)"
      timestamp = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.localTimestamp)"
    }
  }
}

variables.tf file
variable "custom_logging_metrics" {
  description = "Map of custom logging metrics with labels and extractors"
  type = map(object({
    name        = string
    filter      = string
    metric_kind = string
    value_type = string
    label_extractors = map(string)
    labels = map(string)
  }))
}

output: ╷ │ Error: Unsupported argument │ │   on main.tf line 441, in resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric": │  441:     labels = each.value.labels │ │ An argument named "labels" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "labels"?    


The error message tells you exactly what you should do in this case. If you go to the documentation of the google_logging_metric resource you will see that the labels field is a block and not a map. Furthermore, you can make the description field optional within the labels map optional, so that it will be set to null if not supplied. Below you'll find an example.
main.tf
resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric" {
  for_each = var.custom_logging_metrics
  
  name             = each.value.name
  filter           = each.value.filter
  label_extractors = each.value.label_extractors
  
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = each.value.metric_kind
    value_type  = each.value.value_type
    
    dynamic "labels" {
      for_each = each.value.labels
      
      content {
        key         = labels.key
        value_type  = labels.value_type
        description = labels.description
      }
    }
  }
}

variables.tf
variable "custom_logging_metrics" {
  description = "Map of custom logging metrics with labels and extractors"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    filter           = string
    metric_kind      = string
    value_type       = string
    label_extractors = map(string)
    labels           = map(object({
      key         = string
      value_type  = string
      description = optional(string)
    }
  }))
}

